# how to configure the angular js state for each client different URL with the same folder structure?

Tags: angularjs

My clients will be like abc,def,pqr but my current state is

`localhost/project/#/login`.

Whenever a client logs in into the application I want show the url as

```
localhost/project/#/abc/dashboard OR localhost/project/#/def/dashboard
```

but the folder structure of all clients will be same.

so how do I provide the state configuration for the above problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the $routeProvider variable (using colon before the name)

example -> $routeProvider.when('/**:ClientName**/dashboard', {

The ClientName variable will be save in "$routeParams.ClientName"

You can read more here : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

Comment: Thanks lishner. but  i am using $stateProvier. 
example: $stateProvider
   .state('pro',{
    url: '/pro',
                                templateUrl : 'pages/pro.html',
    controller  : 'proCtrl'
   })

Comment: It should work the same.

$stateProvider
    .state('contacts.detail', {
        url: "/contacts/:contactId",

OR

url: "/contacts/{contactId}"